# Como evitar scroll em imagem?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Evitei ao máximo pedir ajuda alguém para meu próprio aprendizado. Mas de todas as dificuldades que venho enfrentando essa não consigo solucionar e é a última etapa do projeto.

Preciso inserir uma imagem de celular no centro da tela. Até ai tudo certo. Pesquisando achei soluções para deixar a imagem **responsiva**. O problema é que a imagem fica com a barra de scroll ativa em resoluções menores. Como faço para a imagem se redimensionar e evitar o scroll?

Segue o código que tenho até o momento.

```
  <style type="text/css">
   body{
   background: #363636;
   }
   .backgroundCell{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   }
   .backgroundCell img{
   max-width: 556px;   /* Máximo da largura da imagem */
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 1139px;  /* Máximo da altura da imagem */
   min-height: auto;      /* Mínimo da altura, por padrão “auto” */
   background-size: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;            
   }
</style>
<div class="main-panel">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <center>
                  <div class="backgroundCell">
                     <img src='assets/img/iphone_bg.png' />
                  </div>
               </center>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pelo jeito você está usando `bootstrap`, então você pode aplicar na imagem a classe `img-responsive`. Além disso, basta adicionar `overflow: hidden` na imagem para não exibir as barras de rolagem.

Comment: Sim @RicardoPontual, estou usando bootstrap. Já tentei com essa classe, não ajudou em muita coisa. Já tentei com a classe citada e também com o overflow. O problema continua. O scroll continua sendo exibido. Acredito que o problema realmente seja o tamanho da imagem, porque ao rola-lo, o restante da imagem aparece.

Comment: Então a barra de rolagem está do container da imagem, que pode ser qualquer um dos divs que a contém, o div com class "backgroundCell" por exemplo. Tentou colocar o `overflow: hidden` nesse div?

Comment: O scroll estava na div main-panel. Fui testando uma por uma até que achei. Agora a imagem fica cortada.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, faça assim:

No .backgroundCell deixe assim:

```
.backgroundCell{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row;
}
```

E automaticamente ele vai alinhar no meio exato da tela!

Exemplo no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ovh4a01m/
OBS: No exemplo eu setei uma altura fixa para o body para funcionar no jsfiddle, mas ai vai depender do seu código!

Comment: O problema persiste, amigo. Obrigado pela tentativa.